# what is / are called

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I'd like to know whether "is" or "are" should be used in the following.

> A lot of what is / are called freelance workers don't earn enough money every month.

Answer (score 2):

Only the plural is correct here in standard English.

> A lot of what *are* called freelance workers don't earn enough money every month

Answer (score 0):

A lot of **those** called freelance workers don't earn enough money every month.

"What" usually refers to inanimate objects

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

**Many** who are called freelance workers. A lot of applies to uncountable nouns.

A lot of who are called freelance workers is not very formal.